# Quarter wave matching layer of a piezoelectric transducer

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, acoustics

I am trying to understand the quarter wave matching between two layers of impedance $Z_1$ and $Z_2$, where $Z_1 > Z_2$. I can understand the electrical transmission line analogy of matching layer but, I am looking for an answer related to the physics of wave propagation involving reflection (involving phase change) and transmission of sound waves.

My understanding: When a sine wave traveling in medium 1 (Impedance $Z_1$) encounters the interface of the quarter wave matching layer (Impedance $Z_m$) it is reflected back with no phase change as $Z_1 > Z_m$, let us call it the first reflected wave. The transmitted wave is phase shifted by $90^o$ in the matching layer and is reflected at the interface of the medium 2 (Impedance $Z_2$) with no phase change and travels back in the matching layer where it is again phase shifted by $90^o$. Finally, this wave is transmitted into the medium 1 where it cancels the first reflected wave as both are $180^o$ out of phase. Therefore the energy is delivered to load effectively.

Can anyone explain this clearly?. I tried to draw the wave diagram but it doesn't help and how is there a $90^0$ phase change in matching layer?

Comment: I know that two sine waves shifted by a quarter of a wave length will have a phase difference of $90^0$ but I am looking for an intuitive answer. For example, maybe by using a wave diagram involving reflections and transmission or any other way would help.